# what do psycopg2's server connection status values mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to output the status of my connection after I open my connection and after I close it. I am getting an output of 1 when I open it and 2 when I close it, but there is no talk about what these values mean in psycopg2's documentation. Does anyone know what the different status values mean?

I am using the `status` function to get the connection status values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are documented status constants and you can find them here: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#connection-status-constants

This does not tell you the numeric representation/value of the it, though. If you print each constant, as I did, you should get this:

```
from psycopg2 import extensions as ext

print(ext.STATUS_READY) #1
print(ext.STATUS_BEGIN) #2
print(ext.STATUS_IN_TRANSACTION) #2  (this is an alias for STATUS_BEGIN)
print(ext.STATUS_PREPARED) #5
```

Note also that the documentation states: "The status is undefined for closed connectons *(sic)*." http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.status

Comment: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/commit/2c836a2935af8ee0fb8f1de197355a33f2812804